D365: Manage bounced email in RTM
I tried to replicate the power flow of the following solution https://community.dynamics.com/blogs/post/?postid=fc860d38-c4e8-4655-9957-d2e1ccbe2cff but flow is not triggered when an email bounces. I have created the following trigger

and while emails are getting bounced during tests, the flow is not triggered. Are there any ideas why this is happening?
